# How Laravel workbech package can auto boot another workbench package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

In Laravel 4 I'm developing 2 distinct workbench packages at the same time.
Packages work in conjunction but I want to keep things separated.
When they will be ready, the second will depend on the first one through Composer and everything will run well (hope so)... but now: How to make the first ServiceProvider auto boot the second ServiceProvider without writing two lines in /app/config/app.php ??

Now they work great adding two lines into 'providers' in /app/config/app.php but I just want to add one line to keep things easier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can call the register method to do this, directly in your service provider.

```
$this->app->register('YourServiceProvider');
```

If you wish to call the register method outside a service provider, you will need to use the `App` Facade.

```
App::register('YourServiceProvider');
```

Comment: So how can I replace `YourServiceProvider` with Tymon's JWT package LaravelServiceProvider for example?