# A package inside a package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating  package in laravel.

I wish for my package to use another package:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

What's the best way to go about using it? I've added it to my composer file, but you also need to add it to your aliases/providers. I've done this inside my test project which is where i test my package, but for other future users of my package, will they have to go in and add aliases/providers or is there an easier way to set this up inside my package?

Comment: I think you can register it in your service provider, but not 100% sure how you should go about it. I look forward to the answer on here as I've been looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use following in your service provider's register function so you don't need to add it in the `app/config/app.php` file in `aliases` array:

```
public function register()
{
    // ...

    $this->app->booting(function()
    {
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('AliasNameForClass', 'Vendor\package\Facades\MainClass');
    });
}\
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992446/741747), could be helpful.

Comment: So how can I use the same thing with Tymon's JWT package for example? Adding, 'Vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Facades\JWTAuth' don't work.